# Выдает ошибку TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Entry' and 'float'

Tags: python, tkinter

Выдает ошибку TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Entry' and 'float', что не так не могу уже второй час понять, помогите пожалуйста. (я новичок, сильно не ругайтесь)

```
from tkinter import *

def slover(a, b, c, g, h):
    n = 2
    a1 = work(f, g, h, n)
    n *= 2
    a2 = work(f, g, h, n)

    while abs(a1 - a2) > 0.1:
        n *= 2
        a1 = work(f, g, h, n)
        n *= 2
        a2 = work(f, g, h, n)
    return a2


def inserter(value):
    output.delete('0.0', END)
    output.insert('0.0', value)

def work(f, z, v, n):
    hei = (v-z)/float(n)
    total = sum([f((z+(k*hei))) for k in range(n, 0, -1)])
    result = hei * total
    return result

def f(x):
    return a*(x ** 4)+b*(x**2)+c


def trap():
    try:
        a_val = float(a.get())
        b_val = float(b.get())
        c_val = float(c.get())
        g_val = float(g.get())
        h_val = float(h.get())
        inserter(slover(a_val, b_val, c_val, g_val, h_val))
    except ValueError:
        inserter('Убедитесь, что ввели все верно')

root = Tk()

root.title('Решение интегралов методом трапеций и правых прямоугольников')
root.geometry('755x500+600+300')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

a = Entry()
a.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
a_lab = Label(text='x^4 +', font='Arial 15').grid(row=1, column=2)

b = Entry()
b.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=10)
b_lab = Label(text='x^2 +', font='Arial 15').grid(row=1, column=4)

c = Entry()
c.grid(row=1, column=5, pady=10, padx=10)
c_lab = Label(text='= ', font='Arial 15').grid(row=1, column=6)

g = Entry()
g.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10,padx=10)
g_lab = Label(text='введите начало координат', font='Arial 15').grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2)

h = Entry()
h.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10,padx=10)
h_lab = Label(text='введите конец координат', font='Arial 15').grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2)

btn1 = Button(text='Решить методом пр. прямоуг.', font='Arial 15 bold', command=trap).grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=30)

btn2 = Button(text='Решить методом трапеций', font='Arial 15 bold', command=trap).grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=3, padx=30)

output = Text(bg='black', fg='green', font='arial 10')
output.grid(row=5, rowspan=6, column=1, columnspan=8, pady=10, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь перемножить виджет `Entry` с числом `float`, вот что происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает из-за того что Python не знает как перемножить объект `текстового поля` и `float`. Для решения данной задачи. Нужно воспользоваться методом `Entry` под названием `get` который извлекает значение в виде строки, после этого мы можем преобразовать ее в нужный нам тип, например `float`

Таким образом мы делаем:

```
float(entry.get())
```

Код не тестировал полностью, но вот это решение должно подойти в конкретном случае.

```
def f(x):
    return float(a.get())*(x ** 4)+float(b.get())*(x**2)+float(c.get())
```

Comment: Да, все получилось, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Матвей, [Что делать с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Пожалуйста)